# Merge [famicom] → [nes] or leave them separate?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I was wondering if we should make [famicom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/famicom) a synonym of [nes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nes). I ask this because essentially the hardware is identical, the major difference being that the plastic cartridges are keyed differently so one won't fit in the other.

As an aside, I should point out that [famicom-disk-system](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/famicom-disk-system) is a hardware add-on, and thus definitely merits a separate tag if that should come up.

Answer (score 3):

The two games in the answer to the single [famicom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/famicom) question appear to only have been released for the Famicom; the wiki articles don't mention the NES, anyways.  To me that implies that there are Famicom-specific questions and that the tags are useful if separate.

Answer (score 1):

They are different systems; leave the separate.  The Famicom is the Japanese predecessor to the US NES.  They will not play each other's games.

Comment: Strictly, that is not true. The chipsets are identical and the systems themselves don't care if it is a Japanese or US game plugged in. There is a physical difference in the cartridge, but a [file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(tool)) will take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose keeping them separate, since I know of at least [one Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Warrior) that indicates the game was changed while being localized to North America.  Therefore, a question about the Famicom version could have a different answer than a question about the NES version.